# In tabular environment, how to decrease the space between text and the separating line

Tags: tables, tabularx, alignment

I am trying to recreate the following picture[image] and here is my attemt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|b{3cm} b{3cm}|}
     \hline
     \begin{tabular}{b{2cm}}
        Name\\
         \hdashline
     \end{tabular}&
     \begin{tabular}{b{2cm}}
     Phone\\
     \hdashline
     \end{tabular}\\

   Roberts,Sherry&
   \begin{tabular}{b{2cm}}
    ~\\
    \hdashline
    \end{tabular}\\

    ~&~\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the output is unsatisfactory.[image: unsatisfactory]

Specifically, I don't know how to lower the text to just immediately above the line. I specifically chose b{2cm} instead of the normal p{2cm}, but the effect is not clear to me. I checked to see cell padding but it seems what folks meant by that term is enlarging the space in a cell rather than decreasing the space. So I don't have any luck here.

Any suggestion about how to achieve what I have in mind will be greatly appreiciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want much simpler markup, more like

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm} p{3cm}|}
\hline
Name&Phone\\[-8pt]
\dotfill&\dotfill\\
Roberts,Sherry&\dotfill\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is indeed a much more elegant solution. Thank you! Also, if you don't mind me asking. Why do you use \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}command?

Comment: @jxhyc delete that line and see. The hline rules will be very close to the text that adds 2pt extra height in each row, makes hline look nicer normally